# Compiler segfault during explicit template instantiation on clang 11

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, clang++

The following explicit template instantiation results in compiler frontend segfault under LLVM `clang++ 11.0` on `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`, using the `clang-cl` interface with `-std=c++17`, regardless of optimization level.

`A.h`

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:

    T value;

    static constexpr auto address = &A<T>::value;
};

extern template class A<float>;
```

`A.cpp`

```
#include "A.h"

template class A<float>;
```

Note that since C++17 `A::address` is an *inline variable* so ODR-using cannot be a problem here.

The compiler behavior is obviously wrong, I already filed a report at the LLVM bug tracker.
Nevertheless, I am still curious about the actual correctness of the code.

Is it an undefined behavior which is handled incorrectly by the compiler, or the code itself is free of any problems and it's only about the compiler. Personally I don't find anything in the standard at the specification of explicit template instantiations which would suggest that the above code is wrong.

**I don't think that the above is *ill-formed*, am I missing something?**

Comment: A compiler shouldn't crash regardless of the input (even though that is formally allowed as "undefined behaviour"), so a bug report might be in order.

Comment: Compiler crashes are compiler bugs and say nothing about the correctness of your code. To work around compiler crashes you will pretty much have to guess-and-test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example class `A`

> ```
> // A.h
> #pragma once
>
> template <typename T>
> class A {
> public:
>     T value;
>     static constexpr auto address = &A<T>::value;
> };
>
> extern template class A<float>;
>
> // A.cpp
> #include "A.h"
>
> template class A<float>;
> ```

used e.g. as in the following example (full [demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B7hWQeRQsBN4OjNo))

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

int main() {
    A<float> af{42.F};  // uses explicit instantiation: no implicit instantiation occurs.
    A<int> ai{43};      // implicit instantiation.
    std::cout << af.*A<float>::address   // 42
        << "\n" << ai.*A<int>::address;  // 43
}
```

is well-formed, and it is naturally a (ICE; internal compiler error) compiler bug that the compiler crashes. Unless your own program also contains uncarefully placed explicit specializations (see below) or is otherwise very different from the minimal example above, your own program should likewise be well-formed.

---

#### Details

[[temp.explicit]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.explicit#14) requires, for an explicit instantiation declaration [**emphasis** mine]:

> If an entity is the subject of **both an explicit instantiation
> declaration and an explicit instantiation definition** in the same
> translation unit, **the definition shall follow the declaration**. An
> entity that is the subject of an explicit instantiation declaration
> and that **is also used in a way that would otherwise cause an
> implicit instantiation** in the translation unit shall be the subject
> of **an explicit instantiation definition somewhere in the program**;
> otherwise the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. [...] An
> explicit instantiation declaration shall not name a specialization of
> a template with internal linkage.

These requirements are all fulfilled the example above, as are the requirements on the definition of `A` to precede the explicit definition of a specialization of it as per [[temp.explicit]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.explicit#5).

Finally, [[temp.spec]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.spec#5) contains the additional requirements that [**emphasis** mine]:

> For a given template and a given set of template-arguments,
>
> - (5.1) an explicit instantiation definition **shall appear at most once in a program,**
> - (5.2) an explicit specialization shall be defined at most once in a program, as specified in [basic.def.odr], and
> - (5.3) **both an explicit instantiation and a declaration of an explicit specialization shall not appear in a program unless** the
>   explicit instantiation follows a declaration of the explicit
>   specialization. An implementation is not required to diagnose a
>   violation of this rule.

(5.1) is fulfilled as the explicit instantiation definition of `A<float>` is located within a single translation unit (a common ill-formed NDR error is to uncarefully place explicit instantiation definitions in headers, where the header is included in more than a single source file). (5.2) does not apply as there is no explicit specialization of `A` present (for any specialization), and (5.3) subsequently does not apply as there is no explicit specialization of the `A<float>` specialization that can conflict with the explicit instantiation definition of the latter.

---

Finally note that, as per [[temp.local]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.local#2), you may use the *injected-class-name* `A` when initializing the static data member `address` of the class template `A`:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    T value;
    static constexpr auto address = &A::value;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the injected class name though, it didn't make a difference.